# what is audienceUris in asp.net MVC4 web.config file while claims authentication using azure adfs

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am not able to get the meaning of "audienceUris" tag in web.config file of mvc4 asp.net project. Can anybody explain me what is the use of this tag and is it compulsory while configuring windows azure adfs with MVC4 application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Audience Uris are uris that are legal to be targets of STS responses.

In other words, if you redirect to the ADFS, it authenticates the user and redirects back and the redirect hits an uri that is not listed as an audience uri, the WSFederationAuthenticationModule will raise an exception.

Think of it as one of security and design measures.

We often reconfigure token handlers to allow arbitrary audience uris but still, the configuration requires at least one valid uri. In our case it is often `http://foo.bar.qux` then to just indicate a dummy uri.